# Kentico error on publish

Tags: kentico

We've come across this error when trying to publish a folder. The folder is 4 levels deep from root. Am I hitting a character limit?

I have tried to reduce the folder name in the Form tab, but i still got the same error. I could create another folder with a reduced character count, which is why i think it's a count limitation.

```
An error occurred during the page action. Please see event log for more details.
Message: 
[DataConnection.HandleError]: 

Query: 
Proc_CMS_Document_UpdateDocumentNamePath

Caused exception: 
Procedure or function Proc_CMS_Document_UpdateDocumentNamePath has too many arguments specified.


Exception type: System.Exception
Stack Trace: 
at CMS.DataEngine.AbstractDataConnection.HandleError(String queryText, Exception ex)
at CMS.DataEngine.AbstractDataConnection.ExecuteQuery(String queryText, QueryDataParameters queryParams, QueryTypeEnum queryType, Boolean requiresTransaction)
at CMS.DataEngine.GeneralConnection.RunQuery(QueryParameters query)
at CMS.DataEngine.GeneralConnection.ExecuteQuery(QueryParameters query)
at CMS.DataEngine.GeneralConnection.ExecuteQuery(QueryParameters query, Int32& totalRecords)
at CMS.DataEngine.DataQueryBase`1.GetDataFromDBInternal()
at CMS.DataEngine.DataQueryBase`1.GetDataFromDB()
at CMS.DataEngine.DataQueryBase`1.GetData()
at CMS.DataEngine.DataQueryBase`1.get_Result()
at CMS.DataEngine.ConnectionHelper.ExecuteQuery(String queryName, QueryDataParameters parameters, String where, String orderBy, Int32 topN, String columns, Int32 offset, Int32 maxRecords, Int32& totalRecords)
at CMS.DocumentEngine.DocumentPathsUpdater.ExecuteUpdateDocumentPath(DocumentPrefixes prefixes, Boolean allCultureVersions)
at CMS.DocumentEngine.DocumentContinuousIntegrationHelper.HandleBulkUpdate(Boolean allowContinuousIntegrationActions, IWhereCondition bulkWhere, Action bulkUpdate)
at CMS.DocumentEngine.DocumentPathsUpdater.UpdatePaths()
at CMS.DocumentEngine.TreeNode.UpdateInternal()
at CMS.DocumentEngine.TreeNode.Update(Boolean useDocumentHelper)
at CMS.DocumentEngine.VersionManager.PublishVersionInternal(Int32 versionHistoryId, Boolean checkPublish)
at CMS.DocumentEngine.WorkflowManager.MoveToStepInternal(TreeNode node, WorkflowStepInfo currentStep, WorkflowStepInfo step, String comment, Boolean increasePublishVersionNumber, WorkflowTransitionTypeEnum transitionType, Boolean handleActions)
at CMS.DocumentEngine.WorkflowManager.MoveToStepInternal(TreeNode node, WorkflowStepInfo currentStep, WorkflowStepInfo step, String comment, WorkflowTransitionTypeEnum transitionType)
at CMS.DocumentEngine.WorkflowManager.MoveToNextStepInternal(TreeNode node, String comment, WorkflowTransitionTypeEnum transitionType)
at CMS.DocumentEngine.WorkflowManager.MoveToNextStep(TreeNode node, String comment, WorkflowTransitionTypeEnum transitionType)
at CMS.FormControls.CMSDocumentManager.ApproveDocument(Int32 stepId, String comment)

Message: Procedure or function Proc_CMS_Document_UpdateDocumentNamePath has too many arguments specified.

Exception type: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
Stack Trace: 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)
at CMS.DataEngine.AbstractDataConnection.ExecuteQuery(String queryText, QueryDataParameters queryParams, QueryTypeEnum queryType, Boolean requiresTransaction)
```

Comment: What version and hotfix of Kentico are you using?  Does your page/document have special characters in the name or url?

Comment: I'm running 9, HF30. There wasn't any special characters, just letters and spaces.

Comment: Looks like the version of the `Proc_CMS_Document_UpdateDocumentNamePath` procedure and the version of the code executing it are not in sync. This might have happened during hotfixing (if the SQL script was not executed correctly). Can you go to the SQL mgmt studio and show us the code of the procedure? + Can you check whether the assembly version is really 9.0.30?